# Is there continuity I would miss if I skipped X-COM and went to X-COM TFTD?

Tags: x-com-terror-from-the-deep

If I were to start playing X-Com 2 (Terror from the Deep), would I miss anything major, plot-wise, or can I simply jump straight to the sequel?

Comment: Don't miss any x-com title! :) (realy play the first title, i think its much better then the second one, the second was not made by the same team, its just a (badly) pimped version of the first title...)

Comment: Honestly I prefer TFTD over the Enemy Unknown or Apocalypse the atmosphere of this game is superb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're very similar games, only the difficulty is much higher on X-Com 2.  If you're interested in the plot that is revealed through researching things, you will miss some things by skipping right to number 2, so I would definitely suggest starting with the original.

Comment: iirc there are also some minor UI improvements in TFTD

Comment: X-Com 2 is more difficult?  Remind to never play that game, since X-Com forced me to cry in a corner...

Comment: TFTD is extremely annoying and difficult (this coming from someone who poured hundreds of hours into the original XCOM).  So many corners and little worthless rooms to search where aliens can pop out at you.  Each level will take hours and is a really slow crawl.  The original xcom is the best imo, but if you want to play a 'modernized' version, check out Ufo Extraterrestials.

Comment: Part of the reason that people believe TFTD is more difficult than the original is that the original had a bug which set all games to the lowest difficulty no matter what difficulty you selected. Using Scott Jones' xcomutil can fix this bug. (it also provides a number of other improvements to the game and works with TFTD too)

Comment: @JasonBerkan try imagining being at a point in X-com where you've got good plasma weapons for all of your soliders, and you are doing well, and then suddenly you run into an enemy that sort of giggles when you shoot them with plasma.  TFTD had more psionic alients in the field iirc and the alien growth was also nastier.

Comment: TFTD was stupidly hard because at later stages, you have no psionic defenses and they can mind control you through walls.  You literally have to split your squad up and hope that you're not ambushed.

Answer (score 4):

I originally played Terror From the Deep before playing the original X-COM, and I had very little trouble following the plot.  Though they are related (some of the aliens from the first make an appearance in the second), you will be just fine playing the second first if you want to.  There are some minor UI / Organization changes that make the second a little easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

I've played the first 3.  While there is some plot that carries over between 1 and 2 you're not missing anything in doing them out of order.  Psionics is greatly nerfed in 2--in 1 if you develop your psionic characters enough it becomes a cakewalk.  (For a challenge I went into the final battle with no weapons at all.  I was able to win the first battle without ever firing a weapon, I had to fire *ONE* shot in the second.)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the increased difficulty in XCOM 2, they're basically the same game but with different "skins". (ie: X-COM being land based & X-COM 2 being ocean based) ProTip: Save Frequently!